# How to set a parent for css selectors with Material UI

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension, with Material UI. I use the inject method, so the extension injects all of the Material UI styles.

I was wondering if I could add a parent selector for the Material UI styling.

When you look at this example:

```
<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiPaper">
.MuiPaper-root {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  background-color: #fff;
}

... 

</style>
```

What I would like to get:

`#MY-ROOT-ELEMENT .MuiPaper-root { }`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it in another way:

```
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { create } from "jss";

const createGenerateId = () => {
   return (rule, sheet) => {
      return `${sheet.options.classNamePrefix}-${rule.key}-***ENTER-UNIQUE-ID-FOR-APP***`;
      };
   };

const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset()
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={createGenerateId()}>
       ...
    </StylesProvider>,
    rootElement
);
```

This way, if you load the Chrome Extension in a page with Material UI, styling will have no interference with each other.